# UIButton is not working on didSelectAnnotationView

Tags: ios, uibutton, mkannotationview

Hi I have custom view in didSelectAnnotationView when user tap on the pin maker I'm displaying the custom view with UILabel and a UIButton everything is working fine but the UIButton is not clickable please tell how to resolve this issue.

My code.

```
     -(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view1
     {
            NSString *bult;

       if ([view1.annotation isKindOfClass:[MapPin class]]) {
            MapPin *annot = view1.annotation;
            NSLog(@"tit%@",annot.nsname);
            bult=annot.nsname;

         }


     myview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-60, -110, 200, 100)];
     myview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
     myview.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
     myview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     [view1 addSubview:test];

     buldingname = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, -15, 150, 80)];
     buldingname.text=bult;
     [buldingname setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
     [buldingname setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
     [buldingname setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f]];
     buldingname.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
     buldingname.numberOfLines = 3;

     [myview addSubview:buldingname];


    moredetail=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    moredetail.frame= CGRectMake(0, 55, 200, 50);
   [moredetail setTitle:@"Click here for more details" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [moredetail addTarget:self action:@selector(nextbtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   [moredetail setExclusiveTouch:YES];
   [myview addSubview:moredetail];


 }
```

My calling method.

```
    - (IBAction)nextbtn:(id)sender
   {
        NSLog(@"click");
   }
```

I have used the above code its not working please tell me where I'm doing wrong how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because the mapView still handles the touch event.
Just add an DetailView in the:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        {
            return nil;
        }

    static NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"Your_identifier";

    MKAnnotationView *view = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"your_annotaion_image.png"];
    }

     view.canShowCallout = YES;

     UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
     [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

     UIImageView *icon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_icon_image"]];
     view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = icon;

     return view;
    }
```

and then you can call:

```
-(void)showDetails:(UIButton*)button
{
   //do your stuff here
}
```

there is absolutely no need to build a annotation callout view yourself, just change the design of the default one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be add sub view to your custom view then its work.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view1
     {
            NSString *bult;

       if ([view1.annotation isKindOfClass:[MapPin class]]) {
            MapPin *annot = view1.annotation;
            NSLog(@"tit%@",annot.nsname);
            bult=annot.nsname;

         }


     myview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-60, -110, 200, 100)];
     myview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
     myview.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
     myview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     [view1 addSubview:myview];

     buldingname = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, -15, 150, 80)];
     buldingname.text=bult;
     [buldingname setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
     [buldingname setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
     [buldingname setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f]];
     buldingname.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
     buldingname.numberOfLines = 3;

     [myview addSubview:buldingname];


    moredetail=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    moredetail.frame= CGRectMake(0, 55, 200, 50);
   [moredetail setTitle:@"Click here for more details" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [moredetail addTarget:self action:@selector(nextbtn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

   [moredetail setExclusiveTouch:YES];
   [myview addSubview:moredetail];


 }
```

check this code